# Assignment operator and copy constructor after matricies multiplication

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Have problem with copy constructor and assignment operator. Have written code to multiply matricies:

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator * (const Matrix &second) const
{
    // Create result matrix
    Matrix result(Rows(), second.Columns());

    // Multiply matricies
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Rows(); i++)
    {
         for (unsigned j = 0; j < second.Columns(); j++)
         {
             result[i][j] = 0.0;

             for (unsigned k = 0; k < Columns(); k++)
             {
                 result[i][j] += m_matrix[i][k] * second[k][j];
             }
         }
    }

    return result;
}
```

In Main code I call the operator:

```
Matrix C = A * B;
```

However code destroys result variable before assignment, how to write such code correctly to return result matrix? Copy constructor is:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& matrix)
{
    AllocateMatrixArray(matrix.Rows(), matrix.Columns());
    CopyMatrixData(matrix);
}
```

Assignment operator is:

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator = (const Matrix& other)
{
    AllocateMatrixArray(other.Rows(), other.Columns());
    CopyMatrixData(other);
    return *this;
}
```

However I see that compiler does not use it - copy constructor is enough.

Comment: `Matrix C = A * B;` is not assignment, it is copy initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns a reference to a local variable, which will be destroyed at the end of the function's scope. Don't do that:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator * (const Matrix &second) const {
     // same as above
}
```

Note that the return value is now a `Matrix` instead of a `Matrix&`.

Comment: Correct, missed that thing. Thanks. Then assignment operator is not necessary here.

Comment: Well that depends on how you've implemented your Matrix class. You normally don't need to define a copy constructor/assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be returning a reference to local variable. By convention the `opertor*`(I mean the two argument version of course) returns a **copy** to the result. Same holds true for the other operations like `operator+`, `operator-` and so on. A reference is returned by the moifying versions of those operators like `operator *=`, `operator +=` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write expressions like C = A*B all C A and B must be "values".

So the return value of `operator*` must be `matrix` and not `matrix&`, espscialy if the `&` refers to a local variable (like `result`) thet will be destroyed at `}` (hence before = is executed).

That said, there are some more issues:

- The sample `Matrix C = A*B` is **not an assignment**: an assignment happens the the value of an **already existent** object is changed. But Matrix C is created contextually: in fact, what it is called here, is the `Matrix` constructor (copy constructor, in this case)
- There could be memory leaks: Although I don't see how the matrices data are handled, your `operator=` 
  seems to allocate new space and then copy the data in it. But what happens to the space containing the old data? Does it remain forgotten around? Is is automatically released by a smart pointer?
- Similarly, just like `=` should dismiss the old data, also the class itself should dismiss its own data on destruction, hence a destructor should also be implemented. Otherwise every time a Matrix is dismissed (like the local `result`), its data will stay around.